# Caliburn Micro Constructor Injection Failed

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

I am learning Caliburn Micro and try to make use of the `EventAggregator` from the [official site](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator).

However, I got an exception

> "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

The message itself is clear but the example doesn't include a parameterless constructor either. If i add one, the constructor with parameter is not hit and the `IEventAggregator` is still not injected correctly.

Here is my publisher VM after adding the parameterless constructor (without it, exception will be thrown):

```
    public MainViewModel() { }

    public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator ea) : this()
    {
        eventAggregator = ea;
    }
```

And here is the bootstrapper i am using:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<MainViewModel>
{
    private readonly SimpleContainer container = new SimpleContainer();

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
    }
}
```

Here is the example from CM:

```
// Creating the EventAggregator as a singleton.
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase {
    private readonly SimpleContainer _container =
        new SimpleContainer();

     // ... Other Bootstrapper Config

    protected override void Configure(){
        _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
    }

    // ... Other Bootstrapper Config
}

// Acquiring the EventAggregator in a viewModel.
public class FooViewModel {
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public FooViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }
}
```

I checked this post ([Inject EventAggregator into ViewModel with Caliburn Micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372268/inject-eventaggregator-into-viewmodel-with-caliburn-micro)) but it simply said nothing why the CM do not invoke the constructor with injection.

I also checked the CM's sample solution but it uses MEF as the DI solution.

What do I miss?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at Caliburn, but are you sure that your bootstrapper is actually started, can get instances, etc? Check out this http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#samples/Caliburn.Micro.HelloSimpleContainer/Caliburn.Micro.HelloSimpleContainer/Bootstrapper.cs simple container sample, it doesn't use MEF or anything

Comment: @MaksimS. The Configure() is executed; I tried to add the Start() to the bootstrapper constructor but no luck. Moreover, the example doesn't inject anything in the VM.

Comment: Don't have anything to test your code on at the moment; however, just took a look at EventAggregator code in the latest build and it _does_ contain parameterless constructor, at least in micro.wpf. Are you by any chance using EventAggregator from Prism, or something else instead of Caliburn's? I know it sounds silly, but still :)

Comment: @MaksimS. Nah I don't use any DI.. I guess have to use other DI framework like prism, mef or ninject after all..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// ... Other Bootstrapper Config
```

It's the other bootstrapper config that's important.

The best option is to install Caliburn.Micro via the [Caliburn.Micro.Start](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.Start/) NuGet package, and have a look at the provided bootstrapper which also uses the `SimpleContainer` provided by Caliburn.Micro.

Here it is in full:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
     SimpleContainer container;

     public AppBootstrapper()
     {
         Start();
     }

     protected override void Configure()
     {  
         container = new SimpleContainer();
         container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
         container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
         container.PerRequest<IShell, ShellViewModel>();
     }

     protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
     {
         var instance = container.GetInstance(service, key);
         if (instance != null)
             return instance;
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not locate any instances.");
     }

     protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
     {
         return container.GetAllInstances(service);
     }

     protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
     {
         container.BuildUp(instance);
     }

     protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
     {
         DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

devdigital is correct. He said

> it is the other bootstrapper configuration that is important.

This is totally correct.

If you are going to use DI *(which `SimpleContainer` does for you)* then you **must override** the `GetInstance(), GetAllInstances(), BuildUp()` methods in your bootstrapper because CM calls those methods when it wants something from the container.

What is happening in your situation is like this:

1. CM tries to show your `MainViewModel` because you specified it as the generic parameter in the Bootstrapper.
2. CM notices that your `MainViewModel` has one constructor that takes an `IEventAggregator`.
3. CM calls `GetInstance()` to get whatever is registered as an `IEventAggregator`.
4. CM figures out that you haven't overriden `GetInstance()` so it tries to create an instance of `MainViewModel` using `Activator.CreateInstance()`.
5. `Activator.CreateInstance()` doesn't know how create an `IEventAggregator` so it throws an exception *(the one you are getting)*.

To fix all of this you have to override the methods i told you about. You don't need to install the Nuget Caliburn.Start package *(you can use it if you don't like typing and you want to save some keystrokes)*.

Essentially your final solution should look like this:

```
public class Bootstrapper : Bootstrapper<MainViewModel>
    {

        private readonly SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            _container.Instance<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
            _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
            _container.PerRequest<MainViewModel>();
        }

        protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
        {
            return _container.GetInstance(service, key);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
        {
            return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
        }

        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            _container.BuildUp(instance);
        }

    }
```