# WPF Caliburn.Micro: Binding DisplayMemberPath on ChildViewModel

Tags: wpf, binding, caliburn.micro

I use VS2013, WPF 4.5, Caliburn Micro 2.0.2. This is a sample project of mine.
My ShellViewModel has base class Conductor and has collection of model (a property) called Vehicles. I created also ChildViewModel that has base class Screen and a property called ParentVm, which contains its parent. In my real project I have surely more than one child viewmodel (thus, > 1 screens)

The model (class Vehicle) contains properties: Manufacturer, Model and Type.

How can I bind DisplayMemberPath of ListBox in ChildView which has ItemsSource="ParentVm.Vehicles", so the ListBox can show the Manufacturer of class Vehicle?

Following is my sample code. Please feel free to modify it to show me the solution. Thank you in advance.

```
public class Vehicle : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public String Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public String Model { get; set; }
    public String Type { get; set; }
}
```

**ShellViewModel**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<Screen>, IHaveActiveItem
{
    public ChildViewModel ChildVm { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        DisplayName = "Shell Window";
        ChildVm = new ChildViewModel(this);
        Vehicles = new ObservableCollection<Vehicle>();
        SetData();
    }

    public void DisplayChild()
    {
        ActivateItem(ChildVm);
    }

    private void SetData()
    { // fill collection with some sample data
        vh = new Vehicle();
        vh.Manufacturer = "Chevrolet";
        vh.Model = "Spark";
        vh.Type = "LS";
        Vehicles.Add(vh);
    }
}
```

**ShellView**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMWpfConductorParentChild.Views.ShellView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Width="300" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="DisplayChild"
                Grid.Row="0" Width="120" Height="40"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                Content="Display Child View" />
        <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ChildViewModel**

```
public class ChildViewModel : Screen
{
    public ShellViewModel ParentVm { get; private set; }
    public ChildViewModel(ShellViewModel parent)
    {
        ParentVm = parent;
    }
}
```

**ChildView** (the binding of DisplayMemberPath below doesn't work)

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMWpfConductorParentChild.Views.ChildView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Width="300" Height="300">
        <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Manufacturer" ItemsSource="ParentVm.Vehicles" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: may be missing DataContext ,  try setting d:DataContext="{x:Type model:ParentVm}"

Comment: @jophy job: where should I set it? in <UserControl ....>? Is it possible to set it only for <ListBox>? Because the other controls in ChildView should have ChildViewModel as DataContext, since Caliburn.Micro uses naming convention between View and ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the 'Binding' keyword to the 'ItemsSource' property:

```
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Manufacturer" ItemsSource="{Binding ParentVm.Vehicles}" />
```

I've modified your example to show how you can bind properties to the child view based on convention.

**ShellViewModel**

```cs
public class ShellViewModel : Screen, IShell
{
    private readonly ChildViewModel _ChildView;
    private readonly IEventAggregator _Aggregator;
    public IList<Vehicle> vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

    public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator aggregator, ChildViewModel childView)
    {
        if (aggregator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("aggregator");
        _Aggregator = aggregator;

        if (childView == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("childView");
        _ChildView = childView;
        DisplayName = "Shell Window";
    }

    public ChildViewModel ChildView 
    { 
        get { return _ChildView; } 
    }

    public void DisplayChild()
    {
        var vh = new Vehicle() { Manufacturer = "Chevrolet", Model = "Spark", Type = "LS" };
        vehicles.Add(vh);
        _Aggregator.PublishOnUIThreadAsync(new ShowChildViewEvent(vehicles));
    }
}
```

**ShellView**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CaliburnDemo.ShellView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
<Grid Width="300" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="DisplayChild"
            Grid.Row="0" Width="120" Height="40"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            Content="Display Child View" />
    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding ChildView}" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

**ChildViewModel**

```cs
public class ChildViewModel : Screen, IHandle<ShowChildViewEvent>
{
    private BindableCollection<Vehicle> _Vehicles;
    private readonly IEventAggregator _Aggregator;

    public ChildViewModel(IEventAggregator aggregator)
    {
        if (aggregator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("aggregator");
        _Aggregator = aggregator;
        _Aggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public BindableCollection<Vehicle> Vehicles
    {
        get { return _Vehicles; }
        set
        {
            _Vehicles = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Vehicles);
        }
    }

    public void Handle(ShowChildViewEvent message)
    {
        Vehicles = new BindableCollection<Vehicle>(message.Vehicles);
    }
}
```

**ChildView**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CaliburnDemo.ChildView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="Vehicles" DisplayMemberPath="Manufacturer" />
</Grid>
```

**ShowChildViewEvent**

```cs
public class ShowChildViewEvent
{
    public ShowChildViewEvent(IList<Vehicle> vehicles)
    {
        Vehicles = vehicles;
    }
    public IList<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; private set; }
}
```

IShell is an empty interface used for resolving the root view from the container. You can find more on conventions in Caliburn here:
[Caliburn Conventions](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/conventions)

Comment: How can I call the constructor ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator aggregator, ChildViewModel childView)? I get System.MissingMethodException. In the AppBootstrapper class there is protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)       { DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>(); }. I have added by following CM Documentation: private readonly SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer(); and  protected override void Configure() {        _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>(); }. Thank you in advance.

Comment: OK I just found out the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802253/caliburn-micro-constructor-injection-failed

Comment: One last question: why do you use Screen instead of Conductor<Screen> on your modification of ShellViewModel?

Comment: I used Screen here since I was assuming no lifecycle management of other screens were needed. You could Conductor<Screen> as well, which is used for managing one screen at a time. If there was an application with tabs (many Screen's) for example, then you could use Conductor<T>.Collection.OneActive, where many Screen's are managed, but only one would be active. Conductors are useful for managing the state of many Screen's, i.e. activate or deactivate.