# Caliburn.Micro Navigation from Usercontrol over ShellViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

## Description

I use the Caliburn.Micro in version 4 and try to navigatie from a Usercontrol to another page. The ShellView.xaml has a `<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />` element and all navigationmethods like `DashboardView()`, `GcsImportView()`... work aslong I am inside the ShellView.xaml. But if I call from a Usercontrol (inside the ContentControl) nothing happens. I don´t even get a error. I can push the Button thousend times without any respond. I hope somebody can help me here.

## Update

Even if I try the code from these [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899727/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-conductors-in-caliburn-micro) it doesn´t work. On debugging the ActiveItem value will be changed. That looks like a bug?

[image]

## ShellViewModel.cs

```
namespace GCS.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>//, IHandle<GcsImportProgressViewModel>
    {
        private string _version = "v. " + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

        public string Version
        {
            get { return _version; }
        }

        public ShellViewModel(/*IEventAggregator eventAggregator*/)
        {
            DashboardView();

            //eventAggregator.SubscribeOnUIThread(this);
        }

        public void DashboardView() => ActivateItemAsync(new DashboardViewModel());
        public void GcsImportView() => ActivateItemAsync(IoC.Get<GcsImportViewModel>());
        public void GcsExportView() => ActivateItemAsync(new GcsExportViewModel());

        public void ChangeView<T>() => ActivateItemAsync(IoC.Get<T>());

        //public Task HandleAsync(GcsImportProgressViewModel message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        //{
        //    throw new NotImplementedException();
        //}
    }
}
```

## UserControl Constructor

```
public GcsImportViewModel(ShellViewModel shell, IGcsRepository gcsRepository/)
        {
            filePath = "Bitte GCS Excel Datei auswählen";
            databases = new ObservableCollection<GcsTable>(gcsRepository.GetAllTables());
            selectedDatabase = databases.FirstOrDefault();

            this.gcsRepository = gcsRepository;
        }
```

## Usercontrol Method to change the view

```
public void ClickImport()
{
    shell.ChangeView<GcsImportProgressViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: Does `shell.DashboardView();` work? Is `ClickImport` invoked as expected? How do you instantiate `GcsImportViewModel`?

Comment: shell.DashboardView(); does only work if it called in the shell xaml. ClickImport is just a button who should change the view and I see with a breakpoint that he jump to ChangeView method. But the view isn´t changing.

Comment: You didn't answer my other questions, particularly the one about how you instantiate the view models.

Comment: I´ve a button with x:Name GcsImportView. There will be load the ActivateItemAsync(IoC.Get<GcsImportViewModel>()); into the contentcontrol

Comment: So? It's still unclear how you create `GcsImportViewModel`?

Comment: IoC.Get<GcsImportViewModel>() create the object with dependency?

Comment: So how are you registering the `ShellViewModel`? Are you sure that you operate on the same instance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234959/discussion-between-lukas-gund-and-mm8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are calling `ChangeView` on a different instance of the `ShellViewModel`.

You should register the view model as a singleton in your bootstrapper:

```
container.Singleton<ShellViewModel, ShellViewModel>();
```